# Linux : Setting which php bin to use in CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, php

Hi i'm trying to use **php** command in linux. However I have **two installations of php,** one I got from the sudo-apt-get and one from a stack, [Lappstack](https://bitnami.com/stack/lapp). Don't ask how I got there, but nevertheless i'm trying to execute php in CLI .

```
$ php file.php
```

it both works whichever php it points to but I want to use the php that I use in the stack.

**when I try to execute :**

```
$ which php
```

**It returns :**

```
/usr/bin/php
```

**But I have to use the php I have in my lappstack which is in :**

```
/home/userName/lappstack/php/bin
```

**How do I change the php bin that my CLI php points to?**

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the second file path to your $PATH variable, and place it at the front, like so:

```
PATH=/home/userName/lappstack/php/bin:$PATH
```

Whichever file path comes first has priority.

Alternatively, you can always specify the full path when using PHP, e.g.:
/home/userName/lappstack/php/bin/php myscript.php.